# AndroidViewClient ERROR: Device is secure

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I'm trying to use AndroidViewClient for some automation. On [github][1] there is a page about "Secure Mode". It states this:

**AndroidViewClient has two possible back-ends:**

- ViewServer
- UiAutomator

**UiAutomator works on Android API 16 and higher, so if your device has a previous version your only alternative is ViewServer.**

I'm trying to run dump.py, but I'm getting the "Device is secure" error. The secure mode page states that "your only alternative is ViewServer". What is viewServer and how do I use it with monkeyrunner?

I'm having a tough time grasping this because according to this image on github page, if I don't have API lvl 16 or higher, I can use the id names if I have them (which I do) I just don't know how to do it.

In summary,

I have devices at API level 15 and lower, and the source code, and I want to automate my application using viewID's. **Is that possible?**

### LAST ERROR:

```
C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools>monkeyrunner C:\AndroidViewClient-master\Andro
idViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\examples\dump.py --ignore-secure-device --
do-not-start-view-server
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
] Script terminated due to an exception
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\e
xamples\dump.py", line 79, in <module>
    ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1), **kwargs2).traverse
(transform=transform)
  File "C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\s
rc\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 991, in __init__
    subprocess.check_call([adb, '-s', self.serialno, 'forward', 'tcp:%d' % self.
localPort,
  File "C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib\jython.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", lin
e 469, in check_call
  File "C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib\jython.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", lin
e 456, in call
  File "C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib\jython.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", lin
e 755, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib\jython.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", lin
e 1269, in _execute_child
OSError: Cannot run program "C:\Windows\system32\adb.exe" (in directory "C:\User
s\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
file specified

130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyException.doRaise(PyException.java:219)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1159)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1163)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1167)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at subprocess$py._execute_child$36(C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib
\jython.jar\Lib\subprocess.py:1270)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at subprocess$py.call_function(C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib\jyt
hon.jar\Lib\subprocess.py)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:297)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:191)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:385)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:215)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyMethod.instancemethod___call__(PyMethod.java:221)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:206)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:367)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:371)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at subprocess$py.__init__$19(C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib\jytho
n.jar\Lib\subprocess.py:844)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at subprocess$py.call_function(C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib\jyt
hon.jar\Lib\subprocess.py)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:297)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:191)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:385)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:215)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyMethod.instancemethod___call__(PyMethod.java:221)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:206)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyObjectDerived.dispatch__init__(PyObjectDerived.java
:1097)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyType.invoke_new_(PyType.java:444)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyType.type___call__(PyType.java:1374)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyType.__call__(PyType.java:1365)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyObject._callextra(PyObject.java:537)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at subprocess$py.call$7(C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib\jython.jar
\Lib\subprocess.py:456)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at subprocess$py.call_function(C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib\jyt
hon.jar\Lib\subprocess.py)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:297)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:370)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.function___call__(PyFunction.java:375)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:365)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyObject._callextra(PyObject.java:537)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at subprocess$py.check_call$8(C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib\jyth
on.jar\Lib\subprocess.py:475)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at subprocess$py.call_function(C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools\lib\jyt
hon.jar\Lib\subprocess.py)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:297)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:124)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:317)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.__init__$54(C:\AndroidViewClient-m
aster\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewcl
ient.py:995)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.dtmilano.android.viewclient$py.call_function(C:\AndroidViewClient
-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\view
client.py)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:297)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:191)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:385)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:380)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyInstance.__init__(PyInstance.java:120)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyClass.__call__(PyClass.java:194)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyObject._callextra(PyObject.java:537)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewCl
ient-master\AndroidViewClient\examples\dump.py:79)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(C:\AndroidViewClient-master\And
roidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\examples\dump.py)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1197)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:538)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:156
)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.
java:77)
130425 14:05:23.047:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions
]       at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter
.java:189)
```

Comment: This is ViewServer: https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer

Comment: This would allow me to use AndroidViewClient for API 15 and lower?

Comment: Why does https://raw.github.com/wiki/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/images/select-implementation-activity-diagram.png mention ViewServer and LocalViewServer? I think that's where my confusion is coming in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device **API** level is **< 16** your alternatives are (as depicted in this [image](https://raw.github.com/wiki/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/images/select-implementation-activity-diagram.png)):

- [LocalViewServer](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Localviewserver) if you have access to application source code. LocalViewServer is a fork of ViewServer
- Use the emulator (secure mode is disabled)
- Root the device and disable secure mode yourself

**LocalViewServer** features **LocalViewServerActivity** which you can extend to simplify **ViewServer** implementation in your Activity.

Check the sample source code at [TemperatureConverterActivity](https://github.com/dtmilano/TemperatureConverter/blob/master/src/com/example/i2at/tc/TemperatureConverterActivity.java).

The reason for the error you posted seems to be:

```
OSError: Cannot run program "C:\Windows\system32\adb.exe" (in directory "C:\User
s\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
file specified
```

You should set environment variable ANDROID_HOME correctly to point to Android SDK installation.

Comment: Okay, I used LocalViewServer to get hierarchy viewer running, but running dump.py still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You're in the right path then. What's the error when you run dump.py?

Comment: C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools>monkeyrunner C:\AndroidViewClient-master\Andro
idViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\examples\dump.py
dump.py: ERROR: Device is secure, AndroidViewClient won't work.

Comment: You have to specify `--ignore-secure-device` and  `--do-not-start-view-server` options to `dump.py`

Comment: Like this: `C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools>monkeyrunner C:\AndroidViewClient-master\Andro
idViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\examples\dump.py --ignore-secure-device an
d --do-not-start-view-server`

Comment: `C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdk\tools>monkeyrunner C:\AndroidViewClient-master\Andro idViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\examples\dump.py --ignore-secure-device --do-not-start-view-server`

Comment: Can't believe I copied and pasted that in. Time to get some sleep. Thanks, so now it runs, but I get a massive error log. I updated my question to show it.